# Насколько критична валидность сайта для поисковых роботов?

Tags: seo, content

Добрый день уважаемые. Скажите пожалуйста, (те кто разбираются в SEO ), насколько критично иметь валидные HTML, CSS, JS коды? (если можно пояснения по каждому пункту)
PS Довольно часто в статьях встречаю выражения. "валидность ради валидности "(написано с сарказмом) вроде как специалисты решают проблемы верстки при помощи заведомо не валидных методов (что б не ставить костылей в код) и считают что это вполне допустимые решения

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.ru%2F

Answer (score 5):

Проблема невалидной верстки - в том, что разные браузеры могут понять ее по-разному. Как следствие, **вы никогда не узнаете, правильно ли поисковой робот понимает вашу невалидную верстку**.

Более того, алгоритмы поисковых роботов меняются. А еще иногда появляются новые - тот же google когда-то давным-давно был непонятным новым сайтом... Валидную верстку любая новая версия робота будет понимать как это и задумывалось. А вот с невалидной может выйти неприятный сюрприз.

---

Надо понимать, что намеренно невалидная верстка - это и есть костыль. Перенеся костыль из кода в верстку - вы от костыля не избавляетесь, как бы не хотелось думать обратное.

А еще надо понимать, что валидность бывает разная. HTML 4.1, XHTML, HTML 5 - это три разных стандарта, и верстка, валидная в одном из них, окажется невалидной с точки зрения другого. Поэтому проверять сайт случайными веб-валидаторами, а потом сразу бросаться исправлять все подряд, и правда не стоит. *Обычно* достаточно добиться чтобы ваш редактор корректно подсвечивал синтаксис и не находил ошибок - последний стандарт (HTML 5) прощает верстке очень многое, и это документированное поведение.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно вы имеете ввиду под валидностью кода - его корректность. Перед тем как браузер отобразит веб-страницу, он должен построить **[объектную модель документа DOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)**.

- Браузер читает исходные байты HTML с диска сервера или сети, и переводит их в отдельные символы, основанные на заданной кодировке файла (например, UTF-8).
- Браузер преобразует строку символов в различные лексемы - как это указано в **[стандарте W3C HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)**. Например, «», «<тело>» - и другие строки в угловых скобках. Каждый маркер имеет особый смысл и свой собственный набор правил.
- излучаемые лексемы преобразуются в «объекты», которые определяют их свойства и правила.
- Строительство DOM: поскольку HTML разметка определяет отношения между различными метками (некоторые теги содержатся в других тегах) созданные объекты связаны в структуре данных дерева, которая также захватывает родитель-потомок, определенные в оригинальной разметке: HTML-объект является родителем объекта тела, тело является родителем объекта пункта, и так далее.

**[Документация W3 о DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)**. Весь этот процесс занимает некоторое время, особенно если у нас есть большое количество HTML для обработки. Чем больше кода, тем дольше браузер обрабатывает его. Это влияет на скорость загрузки страницы, что является критичным для мобильных пользователей - статистика сообщает, что они ждут не более 3-х секунд, а затем уходят. А это в настоящее время - между 50% и 60% всего трафика в сети. Вы можете видеть, что чтение/создание DOM - это довольно сложный процесс. Теперь представьте, что в исходном коде страницы имеется только одна ошибка (не говоря уже о многих ошибках), или даже имеется Фатальная ошибка. Вы можете видеть, как усложняется работа браузера в этом случае. Стандарт ХТМЛ5 довольно либеральный и браузер может понять концепт вашей веб-страницы, даже, если исходный код имеет несколько ошибок. Но чем больше ошибок, тем более размывается смысл концепта веб-страницы и тем больше времени браузеру требуется. Из-за этого увеличивается скорость загрузки. Также множественные ошибки исходного кода мешают правильно понимать веб-страницу для мобильных пользователей. Кроме того, с исходным кодом тесно связана структурированная разметка. Эта разметка применяется для богатой выдаче в поиске + для голосового поиска + для машинного обучения. Наконец, ошибки исходного кода - это нарушение стандарта ХТМЛ5. **В итоге только с ошибками исходного кода вы можете получить: потеря 50%-60% трафика - мобильные пользователи, проблемы веб-сайта в мобильном индексе, браузеры и поисковики не могут правильно понимать ваш сайт и его структуру, понижение поискового ранга**.

Answer (score 1):

> насколько критично иметь валидные HTML, CSS, JS коды?

Ответ на этот вопрос можно ОЧЕНЬ просто найти самостоятельно. Берёшь сайты из ТОПа и проверяешь на валидность.
*И попробуй найти хотя бы один 100% валидный  :)*

Но это вовсе не значит что нужно намерено допускать косяки.

> Довольно часто в статьях встречаю выражения. "валидность ради
>   валидности "(написано с сарказмом)

Это толстый намёк на то, что не стоит вылизывать валидность на уже живом сайте, не тобой сверстанным изначально (всех его элементов). Лучше силы отдать на более продуктивные занятия.